Should deeksha/spiritual advice be given only when asked?
Now a days people suggest mantras and vratas even when people have not surrendered to them as disciples.or to those who have not asked for spiritual guidance..what are are the necessary conditions for giving spiritual guidance?
My question is-is it valid to give deeksha to someone who has not surrendered to them?

It is wrong as per Manusmriti

नापृष्टः कस्य चिद् ब्रूयान्न चान्यायेन पृच्छतः । जानन्नपि हि
मेधावी जडवल्लोक आचरेत् ॥ ११० ॥
One should not instruct any one unless he is asked; nor any one who
asks in an improper manner. even though knowing (the truth), the wise
man should behave, among men, as if ignorant.Chapter II—(110)


Srimad Bhagavatam [Bood-4, Chapter: 8 and 9] talks about Story of Dhruva, son of King Uttānapāda and Sunīti, who wanted to sit at the lap of his father, but was interrupted by his step-mother Suruci. Being cut to the quick by the harsh words of his stepmother, Dhruva went away crying to his mother. Sunīti took up on her lap, "Oh child! Remain above jealousy. Abide by the true path even though it is advised by your step-mother. If you desire the highest seat (throne) like Uttama, propitiate the feet of Bhagavan Vishnu". Having heard the words thus spoken out to him, Dhruva controlled his mind by his will power, and left his father’s capital towards forest. [Slokas: 7-24].
Devarishi Nārada intercepts the boy and gives upadesam (Dīksha) with mantra [sloka: 54]:
ॐ नमो भगवते वासुदेवाय ॥ ५४॥
oṃ namo bhagavate vāsudevāya ॥ 54॥

If Prārabdha Karma (प्रारब्ध कर्म/begun/commenced) is so, then definitely any body may receive Dīksha(दीक्षा) from unexpected quarters without asking.
